Git submodules - working with serverless, vite and shared ui components
I have a project which uses git submodules.
In this project I have three submodules:

BFF ( a serverless project that creates lambdas)
UI ( a vite react project)
Core (a folder which contains files I need to share between BFF and UI)

I am able to share all the files between CORE and UI by adding the package dependency in the package.json file of my UI project like so: "core": "workspace:*"
I have included the same on my BFF package.json file, but here I am having some issues.
When I launch the script to deploy serverless offline (for local development)
SLS_DEBUG=* && env-cmd -f ./.env node --inspect ../../node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless offline --reloadHandler --localEnvironment true -s local --verbose
I get this error:

Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'core/src/utils/caseInsensitive'

which indicates that the file I am trying to import from CORE cannot be found.
I have already checked the path and it is pointing to the correct location when imported in the BFF project
import { arrayIncludes } from 'core/src/utils/caseInsensitive'
I tried to fiddle around with tsconfig on both projects as I though it was something related to that, but still no luck.
The tsconfig of BFF is as follows:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "core/*": [
        "../core/src/*"
      ]
    },
  }
}

while the tsconfig for the CORE project is this one:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
}


Please let me know if you require additional details.
Thanks
